# Prove that the set of elements of finite order in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Prove that the set of elements of finite order in $G$, that is $T(G) :=\bigg{\{} g \in G \space  \bigg{|}  \space|g| <  \infty
> \bigg{\}}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Proof

- Since $1 \in G$ and $|1| <\infty$, $1 \in T(G)$ therefore $T(G)$ is non empty.
- Let take any $a,b \in T(G)$ say $|a|=n<\infty$ and $|b|=m<\infty$.

  Consider, $(ab^{-1})^{nm}=a^{mn}(b^{-1})^{mn}=(a^n)^{m}((b^{-1})^{m})^n=1$.

Therefore $|ab^{-1}| \leq nm$ that is $|ab^{-1}|<\infty$. So $ab^{-1} \in T(G)$. By the subgroup criterion  $T(g)$ is a subgroup of group $G$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: Looks fine! Only I'd write $|1| = 1 <\infty$.

Comment: Also state where you used the assumption that G is abelian.

Comment: @AHusain Thank you vey much

Comment: The $T$ in $T(G)$ stands for [torsion subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup). Compare also your solution yourself with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484249/in-an-abelian-group-the-elements-of-finite-order-form-a-subgroup?rq=1).